# Strange claim about the number of primes between two given numbers.

Tags: number-theory, distribution-of-primes

I recently saw a meme posted to the Facebook group "Mathematical Mathematics Memes."

The meme listed some results about the number of primes between two given numbers.

The last result listed seems too good to be true, and I have never seen it before. The result says:

"For every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N$ such that for every $n\geq N$, there exists a prime number $p$ between $n$ and $(1+\epsilon)n$."

Is this statement true, or are they just meming? If so, could you supply a reference?

Comment: It's true. See [Wikipedia's entry for Bertrand's Postulate, section "Better results"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate?wprov=sfti1#Better_results) and references there

Comment: If $n$ is large enough $\epsilon n$ can be a large range of numbers. For example, if $\epsilon=.0001$ then $\epsilon 1000000=100$ so we are saying there is a prime number in a range of one hundred numbers starting at a million. It doesn't seem that hard to believe when we consider that $N$ can be much larger than that.

Comment: The prime number theorem and in particular the Dusart bounds establish this property.

Comment: For example, if there are arbitrary large m with no prime between m and m + m/1000 then the function n / (pi(n) ln (n)) would be c* (n / ln n) for some constant c and n between m and m + m/1000, for arbitrary large m, which should be enough to stop it from converging.

Comment: FYI, coincidentally just a few hours earlier, a quite similar question of [Prime-less intervals $[n,\lfloor q\cdot n\rfloor]$ for $q\in \mathbb{Q}, q>1$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/458660/129887) was asked on MathOverflow.